# Is there a way to watch satellite channels on PC for free?

Tags: tv

Is there a way to watch satellite channels on PC for free? I am talking about some specific free-to-air channels.

I have technical details like satellite, band, transpoder Number, Downlink frequency etc. of the channel.

Is there a way I could translate all of this to watch this channel on PC, using some software or webapp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to receive satellite signals and watch free-to-air channels, you need

- A satellite dish (...)
- A satellite capable TV card for your PC (something like [this](http://www.hauppauge.com/site/products/data_novahds2.html))

The TV cards mostly come with software to browse free channels and also record video.

Comment: yes, but I thought there might be a webapp that has a dish and once I tell it the channel info, it simply streams the channel using its own dish.  What I am saying is not technically impossible.

Comment: Maybe so, but I'm not sure if this is legally possible. If you're looking for a web app, this is not the place to ask anyway.

Comment: feel free to delete this q if you have mod powers.

Comment: You could ask about a specific web app on [Webapps.SE], but I can't promise anything.

Comment: well, I did and they closed the question indicating it's off-topic?!

Comment: I said, I can't promise anything!